# Using parallax plugin multiple times on a page?

Tags: jquery, parallax

I am using this plugin that github uses for it's parallax effect:

https://github.com/cameronmcefee/plax

It is a great plugin but I would like to use it more than once on a page.

```
//PLAX - ONE
$('#one img').plaxify()
$('#one .back').plaxify({ "xRange": 50, "yRange": 0 })
$('#one .front').plaxify({ "xRange": 30, "yRange": 0, "invert": true })
$.plax.enable({ "activityTarget": $('#one ') })

//PLAX - TWO
$('#two img').plaxify()
$('#two .back').plaxify({ "xRange": 50, "yRange": 0, "invert": true })
$('#two .front').plaxify({ "xRange": 30, "yRange": 0 })
$.plax.enable({ "activityTarget": $('#two ') })
```

So this is not working and I'm sure there is something simple I can do to be able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this github project](https://github.com/cameronmcefee/plax/blob/master/examples/dynamic.html).